# Is this a bug in civicrm/case/activity/view breadcrumb?

Tags: civicase, activity

Disable popups in display preferences.

Find a case eg     civicrm/case/search?reset=1.

'Manage' the case to open it.

Click on    the activity Subject, goes to eg    civicrm/case/activity/view?cid=203&aid=642

The 'Case Activity'    breadcrumb links to civicrm/case/activity?reset=1 which gives an error when you try to use it:

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
required params missing.

Can reproduce this on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: I'd say ideally the breadcrumb for that activity would be the activity's manage case page. It's obviously just taking the same url path but one level up to construct the breadcrumb, but civicrm/case/activity by itself doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Sounds like its a bona fide bug - will report against https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/165

Answer (score 2):

That was logged to gitlab & Coleman provided a fix which was merged - I think it missed the 5.3 rc so will be in 5.4